# How do I give two equations different reference numbers on the same line?

Tags: equations

Consider the following equation:

```
\begin{align}
 & A x = b & C x = d.
\end{align}
```

Is there a possibility to count both the left equation and the right equation separately, so I can refer to them separately? I would prefer if this is done without subequation, so the count continues.

Comment: The problem is, what you show would not provide two equation numbers, but only one.  Thus, how to tell them apart by reference?

Comment: Can I show two reference numbers (on the same line)? Maybe using minipage or something similar makes it possible to make two equations on the same line, but I hope that there is an easier and more elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you! It is a solution. This is in some sense the naive method and I hoped that there is a easier / more elegant solution.

Comment: @Vincent Such a numbering will only confuse your readers.

Comment: I am afraid you're right. I will probably give the complete line one reference. I only have to refer to the two equations individually once and then this might be an overkill. THe solutions given on the other page are none of them easy. If anyone knows an easy solution, please state it.